# WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following query. And I am facing the above error.

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause, unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
SELECT student_id, 
       class_id, 
       item_id, 
       (SELECT stock 
        FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
        WHERE  stock_reporting_date = Min(stock_reporting_date) 
               AND item_id = dcs.non_mrp_item_id) AS Stock 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
GROUP  BY student_id, 
          sap_customer_id, 
          item_id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query aggregate may not appear in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166626/sql-query-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

**Your subquery must return only one row and one column and then aggregate the value. See changes**

```
SELECT student_id, 
       class_id, 
       item_id, 
       sum((SELECT sum(stock) stock
        FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
        WHERE  stock_reporting_date = stock_reporting_date 
               AND item_id = dcs.non_mrp_item_id)) AS Stock 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
GROUP  BY student_id, 
          sap_customer_id, 
          item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter the the results with aggregate function in WHERE clause you need to use `HAVING` for this for more consistency your virtual column from subquery should return one result for this put `TOP 1`

```
SELECT student_id, 
       class_id, 
       item_id, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 stock 
        FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
        HAVING stock_reporting_date = Min(stock_reporting_date) 
               AND item_id = dcs.non_mrp_item_id) AS Stock 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
GROUP  BY student_id, 
          sap_customer_id, 
          item_id
```

Comment: LIMIT is not available in SQL-Server instead it is MySQL specific

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT student_id, 
   class_id, 
   item_id,
   (SELECT stock 
    FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details dcs
    WHERE item_id = dcs.non_mrp_item_id 
    HAVING stock_reporting_date = Min(stock_reporting_date)) as Stock 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
GROUP  BY student_id, 
      sap_customer_id, 
      item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aliases otherwise SQL Server assumes that `stock_reporting_date` column is part of subquery table (`y` in this case):

```
SELECT x.student_id, 
       x.class_id, 
       x.item_id, 
       (SELECT y.stock 
        FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details y
        WHERE  y.stock_reporting_date = Min(x.stock_reporting_date) 
               AND y.item_id = x.item_id) AS Stock 
        -- I used x.item_id column instead of non_mrp_item_id
        -- If you have to use x.non_mrp_item_id instead of x.item_id then you need to replace this column within GROUP BY clause 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details x
GROUP  BY x.student_id, 
          x.sap_customer_id, 
          x.item_id
```

Also, in this case you need an UNIQUE index on item_id and stock_reporting_date columns otherwise you need to use an aggregate function (MIN, MAX, etc: `(SELECT MAX(y.stock) ...`) or TOP (`(SELECT TOP(1) y.stock ... ORDER BY ...)`) within subquery.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why you use group by.you can remove in my query.Also in your query

```
AND item_id = dcs.non_mrp_item_id
```

is not clear,you can include it .just make it work.

```
Select student_id, 
   class_id, 
   item_id,
    stock 
FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details 
WHERE  stock_reporting_date =(select  Min(stock_reporting_date) FROM   dbo.daily_closing_stock_details GROUP  BY student_id, 
          sap_customer_id, 
          item_id  )
```