# Insert Trigger: Need to split incoming string into two different Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database is being populated by kepware connected to a PLC. I have a kepware tag name of 
"H-T1XX2.Distro_PLC.St 10 Cycle Timer" and I want to split it up based on the periods (".") "H-T1XX2' = WorkCenter and "St 10 Cycle Timer" = Station. Any help would be appreciated.

Looking for help with the pulling the string from the table and splitting the string.

```
USE [StationCycleTime]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [MES].[plcPRODInsert]    Script Date: 1/24/2020 11:04:58 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[plcInsert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @WC varchar(10)
    declare @ST varchar(20)
    declare @InStr varchar(50)
    declare @MaxID varchar(50)

    SELECT @MaxID = n.ID
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] n
    WHERE n.[ID] = MAX(ID)

    SELECT @InStr = m.Station
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] m
    WHERE m.[ID] = @MaxID

    SET @WC = (SELECT PARSENAME(@InStr,3))
    SET @ST = (SELECT PARSENAME(@InStr,1))

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE  [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime]
    SET [WorkCenter] = @WC, [Station] = @ST 
    WHERE [ID] = (
        SELECT MAX(ID) from [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime])
END
```

[Error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdFGc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query aggregate may not appear in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166626/sql-query-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-where-clause)

Comment: You should use the `inserted` table to get the `ID` and `Station`, then split from there and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. To get the max id of a table you can use the Top in SQL Server. I am not sure how it will work.

The below line gives the maximum value of the Id field.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID from [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] ORDER BY ID DESC
```

So, try this alternatives.

```
 UPDATE  [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime]
    SET [WorkCenter] = @WC, [Station] = @ST 
    WHERE [ID] = (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID from [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

The best thing about the trigger is that it gives two magic tables named `inserted` and `deleted`. You should use that inserted tables to get the max id of the - i.e., inserted and deleted values as shown below.

```
WHERE [ID] = inserted.ID -- To get the inserted id values.
```

Here is the documentation of [inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Got it thank you for the help.

---

```
BEGIN
    declare @WC varchar(10)
    declare @ST varchar(20)
    declare @InStr varchar(50)

SELECT @InStr = m.Station
FROM [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] m
WHERE m.[ID] = (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID from [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime] ORDER BY ID DESC)

SET @WC = (SELECT PARSENAME(@InStr,3))
SET @ST = (SELECT PARSENAME(@InStr,1))

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE  [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime]
SET [WorkCenter] = @WC, [Station] = @ST 
WHERE [ID] = (
    SELECT MAX(ID) from [dbo].[tbl_CycleTime])
END
```